# iOS Dynamically loaded custom fonts in WidgetKit widget extension not working on real device? (simulator is fine)

Tags: ios, swift, widgetkit

**<TLDR;>**; *Trying to use a downloaded font via CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL in a widget does not work on a real device. (works on simulator). Seems that registering the font works, but there is a permission issue when loading the font*

```
error   14:39:07.672799-0800    chronod [com.x.y.widgetx:widgetx:small:1536744920620481560@148.0/148.0/20.2] reload: could not decode view
error   14:39:07.674984-0800    kernel  Sandbox: chronod(2128) deny(1) file-read-metadata /private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/9B524570-1765-4C24-9E0C-15BC3982F0DC/downloadedFonts/Chewy/Chewy-Regular.ttf
error   14:39:07.675762-0800    kernel  Sandbox: chronod(2128) deny(1) file-read-data /private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/9B524570-1765-4C24-9E0C-15BC3982F0DC/downloadedFonts/Chewy/Chewy-Regular.ttf
```

**</TLDR;>**

Project structure is:
App target + widget extension + widget intent extension

**All share a common appgroup group.com.x.y.z** and all file handling is done using

```
FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.x.y.z")
```

so that only the shared container is used.

Using the Main app target, a font "Chewy-Regular.ttf" is downloaded and saved to the shared AppGroup container.

Font can now be loaded via:

```
CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL()
```

and displayed in a Main App Text view:

```
Text("Testing...").font(Font.custom("Chewy-Regular", size: 20))
```

Now add a Widgetkit widget instance that uses this font.

In 'getTimeLine() and getSnapShot() of IntentTimelineProvider we load the font again via CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL (this needs to happen again probably because widget runs in a separate process from the main app?).

**On simulator, the widget will show the correct font.
BUT
On iPhone7 real device, the widget will show the 'redacted placeholder view'.**

I see in the device console :

```
error   14:39:07.567120-0800    chronod No configuration found for configured widget identifier: D9BF75EE-4A04-441A-8C85-1507F7ECE379
fault   14:39:07.625600-0800    widgetxExtension    -[EXSwiftUI_Subsystem beginUsing:withBundle:] unexpectedly called multiple times.
error   14:39:07.672733-0800    chronod Encountered an error reading the view archive for <private>; error: <private>
error   14:39:07.672799-0800    chronod [com.x.y.widgetx:widgetx:small:1536744920620481560@148.0/148.0/20.2] reload: could not decode view
error   14:39:07.674984-0800    kernel  Sandbox: chronod(2128) deny(1) file-read-metadata /private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/9B524570-1765-4C24-9E0C-15BC3982F0DC/downloadedFonts/Chewy/Chewy-Regular.ttf
error   14:39:07.675762-0800    kernel  Sandbox: chronod(2128) deny(1) file-read-data /private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/9B524570-1765-4C24-9E0C-15BC3982F0DC/downloadedFonts/Chewy/Chewy-Regular.ttf
error   14:39:07.708914-0800    chronod [u 8D2C83B3-A6CB-432E-A9D4-9BC8F7056B10:m (null)] [<private>(<private>)] Connection to plugin invalidated while in use.
fault   14:39:07.710284-0800    widgetxExtension    -[EXSwiftUI_Subsystem beginUsing:withBundle:] unexpectedly called multiple times.
error   14:39:07.803468-0800    chronod Encountered an error reading the view archive for <private>; error: <private>
```

*It seems that it's a permission issue, and the textview can't access the font file it needs when the widget is rendering.*

Notes:

1. Font is definitely registered because I can see them in

   for fontFamily in UIFont.familyNames {
   for fontName in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: fontFamily) {
   print(fontName)
   ...

in both the Main App target and the Widget Extension target

2. If I make make the font part of the app bundle and add to 'Fonts provided by application' , the are loaded absolutely fine in the Main App and the Widget on simulator and iPhone 7 real device.
3. I do see this error sometimes in the Widget extension target log, don't know if it's related.

   widgetxExtension[1385:254599] [User Defaults] Couldn't read values in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x28375b880> (Domain: group.x.y.z, User: kCFPreferencesAnyUser, ByHost: Yes, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: Yes): Using kCFPreferencesAnyUser with a container is only allowed for System Containers, detaching from cfprefsd
4. I suspected something to do with app groups, so I tried to copy the font into the Widget Extension container and load from there with FileManager.default(), but had the same result.

Please help! Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to read the downloaded font file as `Data`, then create `CTFontRef` from data via `CGFontCreateWithDataProvider` and register it via `CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont`?

Comment: Yes, tried that and it does not work even in the simulator - from https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/659332
it seems that CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont will not work in widgets but CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFontsForUrl is supposed to work.

Comment: I had the same problem. Can anyone help? Thank you so much.

Comment: You can check that the font file has the correct permission and modify it if needed.

Comment: Yeah. After download the `ttf` file. I move the `tmp` file to App Group Container by this code: `try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: cachePath)`,`try FileManager.default.setAttributes([.protectionKey: FileProtectionType.none], ofItemAtPath: cachePath.absoluteString)`.  However, font can still only be used in apps, not in widget extensions.

Comment: Is that correct? @BorislavGizdov

Comment: I don't believe file permissions are the problem here. I managed to create fonts in the widget using both CTFontManagerCreateFontDescriptorsFromURL and CTFontManagerCreateFontDescriptorsFromData. You can even inspect their attributes. But they won't display. Even more strange: you CAN use installed fonts in the widget, without the need for a font 'capability'.

Comment: Even weirder; when I install a font using the iOS 13+ method, the font is **not** available to the widget. Fonts installed via a configuration profile **are** available.

Comment: Can you please share a piece of code, if you managed to display dynamically loaded font (from URL) inside widget? I'm struggling with the same issue for days now..

Comment: Attention. the same code runs perfect in simulator desktop widget, but trigs render error in REAL DEVICE. The condition judgment `FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: cachePath)`(cachePath is AppGroupContainer path) returns `false` in real device, but `true` in simulator.